# What is a good idea to save "Chat" data in database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on a Chat website. I am using asp.net and SQL Server 2008

The idea will be same like normal chatting websites. My problem is, I do not understand how to create a good database design.

I have good knowledge of vb asp.net with SQL Server.

In my project, I created a table for adding new user with `ID, uName, uPassoword` and `uDetail` columns.

Then.... I created a table named `User_Friends (uName , uFriendName)`.

Suppose when user "abc" add new friend it save the relation uName = "abc" and uFriendName ="xyz" in this table, same all other users will do to add there friends and all that data will go in one table (`User_Friends`). All detail that who is whose friend information is in this `User_Friends` table.

My question is:

- But what if there are 10000 users or more and each user add many friends as friend in DB.
- Same thing if I want to save each user chat in DB. Should I use one table for all users chat history or something else.

Then WILL IT BE A SLOW PROCESS TO GET DETAIL FROM ONE TABLE OR NOT?

Please advice me how to design DB or give me some useful links for help.

Comment: Typically in SQL Server, you need a **good DB design** and a good **indexing strategy** and then you can handle gazillions of rows for each table - that's not the bottleneck, for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

saving chat data into database is a space consuming task, i would prefer you to do it this way:

1. user A chats with his friend B... once the chat window is closed make a text file of it
   and save it into a folder structure like Year/Month/Date with file name as 'userid+user friend id' eg: AB.txt
2. For every day keep appending data to the same text file. so in future we will show all chats done in a day in a single file.
3. Add a table chat history with Id,File Name,Created Date Time. Check if that file name already exists in DB if present take that file and append data to it 
   else insert a row with fully qualified path into DB and save chat data into it

Comment: i feel this is a good idea. what if i use access .mdb file insted of text file.

Comment: yes even that will serve the purpose but i prefer text file as it is easy and doesn't take much time in opening and working on it. Please mark as answer if u feel i helped you solve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look to this discussion about same isue ..  [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967856/each-web-online-user-connect-with-there-own-acces-mdb-how-to-do-that#comment12754259_9967856

Comment: But there is a possibility of having bottlenecks using SQL server also as your question implies of having thousands of users

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on how you want to use the stored data.

for the user structure I would recommend to make relationship (friend,blocked,...whatever) in a separate table i.e.

table "user": user_id, nick, name, email, status, ....
table "relation": user_id1, user_id2, relation_type

it is more flexible since you are not limited how many users are on any side of the relationship but it also add some complexity.

regarding message history I would record each message in table like:

table "messages" message_id, send_by, send_to, timestamp, message_text

and do cleaning of messages that are older than .... I suppose you don't need whole history anyway.

regarding performance it is slightly different matter. Databases are designed to handle a lot of data but if you don't index them properly then it will be slow. Finish you table design first. And think about indexing later - based on what type of queries you will execute.