# each web online user connect with there own acces .mdb? how to do that

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, dataset

in my project, when a new user register online on my website, then my project create a directory on server with the user name "abc" and copy a myDB.mdb file in it.

this .mdb file contains predefined 2 tables.

now my question is :

1 is it possible to connect and use with Dataset.xsd in this task.

2 how each user read and write data with there own myDB.mdb file

3 how to make the connection string flexible. so it ll connect with each user myDB.mdb file.

I don't have any clue that how to complete it. i worked with dataset.xsd and vb asp.net but those were static dataset.xsd or predefined .xsd

JS

Comment: I work in Access a lot and I also program for web using ASP. I would never attempt to use an Access database for this. I think SQL Server is your best option because ASP.Net works well with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, please don't do this. You really, really, really need to avoid this approach at all possible costs.

I strongly suggest that you install the free [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx), or [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), or any other multi-user database and store your data in there instead.

Doing this will preserve your sanity both when creating the initial implementation and when you have to update a column or a table in all of the MDBs that have been created for your end users.

Comment: I have sql server 2008 and mysql installed on my hosting server.. I am working on a Chat website. so what if 10,000 users added and each user add more and more friends. will it be a slow process or not.... and what in my chat website i need to save user chat history too. .. i feel if 1000 user read and write same time in same tables it ll be slow .. please give me some advice .. thank you

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to be concerned about thousands of simultaneous accesses to a proper database as long as your database design is good. This is exactly what these databases are designed for. In fact, in your scenario, you have a much worse problem due to the need to have 1000 simultaneous open connections to MDBs.